# How to exclude one record from table through sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to exclude one record from my result output.. I have period of output as sliced as shown below ,in that result "02-JUN-21 30-JUN-21" is not required, how to skip that record  of the date falling through the below query

Below is the select query

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(start_date),
    TRUNC(end_date) 

FROM 
    lease_repayment
WHERE 
    id = 15103
    AND person_id = 16523
    AND lease_unit_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    TRUNC(start_date), TRUNC(end_date)
ORDER BY
    TRUNC(start_date), TRUNC(end_date)
```

Output as:

```
01-JUN-21   01-JUN-21 
02-JUN-21   14-JUN-21
02-JUN-21   30-JUN-21 --- need to avoid this record bcz already 02-14 and 15-30 is avail in the sliced record
15-JUN-21   30-JUN-21
```

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data.

Comment: Please provide the sample data. As a hint use lead and lag function.

Comment: Can be tricky! What if the data contained 2-13 JUN and 15-30 JUN? Should it then display the 2-30 JUN? Or 2-14 JUN exists and 15-25 JUN exists? What to do then?